# HTML parsing error KB927917 IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am getting this error in IE 8 .

But not in all IE 8.

In some system web page is working fine , some are not.

Is it because of some settings.

Enabling or disabling some script will do the magic?

If anyone have gone through this error and solved :) please suggest.

Comment: Please post a link to the page with the problem. Also, try running your page through http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Maybe you should let Microsoft know about this too, because IE8 is not supposed to get this message. ;P http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927917

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your users may be running IE8 as IE7 compatibility mode, if that breaks the code you need to detect document.documentMode  and  branch a fix for IE7.

To find the problem code, run it in compatibility mode yourself and use the IE8 debugger.

Answer (score 8):

You have to check if the dom is loaded:

```
$(function(){ 
   ...
});
```

I got the same error as well, I couldn't reproduce it on all IE8. But this solved it!

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/db34068c-5307-4ab7-be03-15b86c2604bb).

This is a known issue in I.E.8 and Microsoft site posts suggests installation of Cumulative Security fix pack version [KB2360131](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13228) to resolve this issue.

I successfully reproduced this issue on two laptops and was able to resolve it after installing this fix pack. I also tried to uninstall this fix pack and issue reoccurred.

Answer (score 0):

The error can be as simple as a missing closing tag in HTML code.

Sample code :

```
<li>
    <a rel="fancy" href="some-highres-image" title="some-title">
        <img src="some-lowres-image" alt="some-name" width="75" height="75" />
        <span class="zoom">Zoom displayed onmouseover</a> <!-- This should be </span> -->
    </a>
</li>
```

where rel="fancy" calls fancybox after dom ready.
The missing closing **span** tag triggers the KB927917 error in IE8 (8.0.6001.18702)

Answer (score 0):

Update to Sudip's solution: As of today, Security Update KB2936068 fixes this error.